# How can I call geolocation API via MQTT?

Tags: geolocation, embedded, mqtt, iot, google-geolocation

I am working on an IoT project in which I am required to use Google's geolocation API. Well I know it can be called via HTTP request, is there any way I can call it via MQTT as I think it will be more power efficient and have publish/subscribe approach as I want?

Comment: so you want to push your location to a  MQTT broker?

Comment: because in MQTT you just dont call anything... you subscribe to a topic....

Comment: Yes I have to push location to a broker. But are you suggesting to use http to get location from geolocation API and this cannot be performed using MTQQ?

Comment: you need to use the API to get the location and then publish that to the broker